# if statement creating currency knowing exchange rate

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

```
- (IBAction)poga1:(id)sender {

    float kurss = 0.702804;

    if ([_lauks2.text isequaltostring:@"") { 

    float atbilde = [_lauks1 floatValue] * kurss; 
    NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%.2f",atbilde];
    NSLog(@"%@",string);
    [_lauks2 setStringValue:string];

    }

    else if ([_lauks1.text isequaltostring:@"") {

    float atbilde2 = [_lauks2 floatValue] / kurss; 
    NSString *string2 = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%.2f",atbilde2];
    NSLog(@"%@",string);
    [_lauks1 setStringValue:string2];

    }

}
@end
```

I am trying to make it work, it work one way from first field to other but not back... i am new at this, so please be gentle :)

I have 2 textfields and one button i need to create formula in both ways - when i input number in one textfied, it shows answer in other. and other way around.

Comment: never use float for money

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little tough to read that code, but on first skim, at least one problem is the spelling of isequaltostring, requires inter-caps, like `isEqualToString`:.  The other problem could very well be that one or both text field outlets is not hooked up, giving you null values for lauks1.  If it's nil, lauks1.text will always be nil and never be `@""`.

Please check that your outlets are hooked up in IB and not nil when this method is called.  Regarding the rest of the code, I think the better test to decide which direction the computation shall take is to test for isFirstResponder on the text fields.  The logic for blank text can be up to you, maybe causing  the other field to be blanked.  It would go like this (I'm also suggesting easier code to follow here in terms of the computation):

```
- (IBAction)pressedConvertButton:(id)sender {

    if ([self.currencyATextField isFirstResponder]) {  // assume you have outlets for the text fields
        float aValue = [self.currencyATextField.text floatValue];
        float bValue = aValue * kCURRENCY_A_TO_B_EXCHANGE;
        self.currencyBTextField.text = [[NSNumber numberWithFloat:bValue] stringValue];
    } else {
        float bValue = [self.currencyBTextField.text floatValue];
        float aValue = bValue * kCURRENCY_B_TO_A_EXCHANGE;
        self.currencyATextField.text = [[NSNumber numberWithFloat:aValue] stringValue];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this

```
- (IBAction)poga1:(id)sender {

        float kurss = 0.702804;

        if ([_lauks1.text length]) { 

        float atbilde = [_lauks1.text floatValue] * kurss; 
        NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%.2f",atbilde];
        NSLog(@"%@",string);
        [_lauks2 setText:string];

        }

        else if ([_lauks2.text length]) {

        float atbilde2 = [_lauks2.text floatValue] / kurss; 
        NSString *string2 = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%.2f",atbilde2];
        NSLog(@"%@",string2);
        [_lauks1 setText:string2];

        }

    }
```

Comment: @TomsRatkevičs with this approach it will  only work when only one textField has valid value. If it both has value then this logic won't work.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use the the text change notifications and whenever the text changes in one field it will be updated in other without the button intervention (If you still want button, track the current editing field in the text change methods and when button is pressed update the other field.)

```
// add the observer
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(textFieldDidChange:) 
                                             name:@"UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification" 
                                          object:nil];

// the method to call on a change
- (void)textFieldDidChange:(NSNotification*)aNotification 
{
    float kurss = 0.702804;

   if(aNotification.object == _lauks1) {
        float atbilde = [_lauks1.text floatValue] * kurss; 
        NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%.2f",atbilde];
        NSLog(@"%@",string);
        [_lauks2 setText:string];
   } else if (aNotification.object == _lauks2) {
        float atbilde2 = [_lauks2.text floatValue] / kurss; 
        NSString *string2 = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%.2f",atbilde2];
        NSLog(@"%@",string);
        [_lauks1 setText:string2];
   }
}
```